# Cannot open Minecraft as another instance is running

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I try to launch Minecraft it says another instance of this is running and they will not be responsible for lost files if I launch. So after about 5 hours of trying to delete files to make it work and deleting all my mods and uninstalling and reinstalling Minecraft I'm out of options.

How do I fix this and normally open Minecraft?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: Just close the other Minecraft window.

Comment: try restarting your java client. It may be something with java and nothing directly with Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing this window means that there is another window, or client of Minecraft currently running from that folder. All you have to do is simply close any other windows of Minecraft you may have open.

Alternatively, go into your process' and ensure that any java/Minecraft processes are stopped before trying to run the new client.

Comment: I have tried that but it still says it and it also says someone else is logged in as me

Comment: @slygunner reboot?