# My minecraft says game already running

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So when I bring up my minecraft launcher, and i click play, it says game already running. I click start anyway and nothing happens?
I've tried reinstalling EVERYTHING. deleted all of the folders and launchers but there isn't any change.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Open Task Manager. Do you see any process with the Java icon present? It should have a name similar to "Java(TM) Platform SE binary..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open Minecraft as another instance is running](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330959/cannot-open-minecraft-as-another-instance-is-running)

Answer (score -2):

Try what @54D said, but even then, Minecraft  shouldn't stop you from launching... I do believe you can skip through if you're that desperate.

Good luck!